# Error in Linear Regression Model , it doesn't works on dataframes . How to fix this?

Tags: python, machine-learning, linear-regression

I was trying to build a Linear Regression model from scratch. I was following a tutorial.

```
class LinearRegression:

    def __init__(self, learning_rate=0.001, n_iters=1000):
        self.lr = learning_rate
        self.n_iters = n_iters
        self.weights = None
        self.bias = None

    def fit(self, X, y):
        n_samples, n_features = X.shape

        # init parameters
        self.weights = np.zeros(n_features)
        self.bias = 0

        # gradient descent
        for _ in range(self.n_iters):
            y_predicted = np.dot(X, self.weights) + self.bias
            # compute gradients
            dw = (1 / n_samples) * np.dot(X.T, (y_predicted - y))
            db = (1 / n_samples) * np.sum(y_predicted - y)

            # update parameters
            self.weights -= self.lr * dw
            self.bias -= self.lr * db
 

    def predict(self, X):
        y_approximated = np.dot(X, self.weights) + self.bias
        return y_approximated
```

This works really good on inbuilt sklearn's dataset but gives an error when I try it on dataframe. In most cases the error is related to fit method and the shape of weights and bias. What is wrong ? Is there any better implementation available ?